# apply AWK in set of data

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am having a file looks like:

```
A 25 27 50
B 99 88 76
```

output should be

```
A: down
B: up
```

rule: if each numric value should be above than 50 then its "up" or "down"

tried :

```
   awk '{ 
    split($2,arr,","); 
    if(arr[3] >= "50") 
    print $0 
  } ' file.txt
```

Comment: your data is not comma separated, splitting with "," is not going to work...

Comment: could be there 3-digit numbers like `102` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) 
          if($i+0<50) {print $1": down"; next} 
        print $1": up"}' file
```

ps. checks for strictly less than 50.  if not change to `<=50`.

Comment: Rule: if each numeric value is above 50 then its "up". You implemented at least 1 value > 50.